# Map.containsValue() returning false

Tags: java, string, collections, set, contains

I have a map as below :

```
final Map<myobj,Set<String>> existingNames = this.getExistingCIs(_actual,_names.keySet());
```

It returns:

```
{myobj43c0e17f0100000606@3508cfdf=[Immutable]}
```

I'm trying to check if the map value contains string "Immutable" then I'm trying to do further logic. But `existingNames.containsValue("Immutable")` throws `false`:

```
if (existingNames.containsValue("Immutable")) { 
    // mylogic
}
```

Is it because of `Set<String>`? If so how to check this? I think I do something wrong while comparing. I have only basic knowledge of Java and not sure how to convert the set to check the string.

Comment: `existingNames.containsValue("Immutable")` checks for a `String` as value. But your map's values are `Set<String>` objects. A `Set` can't be conceptually equal to a `String`, can it?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Comment: @ernest_k , yes i agree. But i dont know how to check the `set` object with mystring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to check whether *any* set *contains* the value is

```
existingNames.values().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("Immutable"))
```

If you want to check that the set is a *singleton* containing the string, then you can create a set inline:

```
existingNames.containsValue(Collections.singleton("Immutable"))
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to check for each Set if it contains the value. You can find it in the Set java doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

you could do:

```
for (Set<String> names: existingNames.values()) {
  if (names.contains("Immutable")) { /* your logic*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you compare the value of the map with a `String`, however, the map's definition is `Map<myobj, Set<String>>`, therefore the direct comparison with the value `Set<String>` will not work the way you do.

Here is the [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) compliant way using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream), the key method is [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which returns `true` whether any elements of the stream match the provided predicate.

To find an element in the `Set` use [`Set::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
existingNames.values().stream().anyMatch(set -> set.contains("Immutable"))
```